# Obfuscated Flutter app, exception and stack are in text format or they are a binary?

Tags: flutter, obfuscation, deobfuscation

I want to send errors/exceptions of an obfuscated Flutter app to a server to record incidents.

They are text variables (to deobfuscate with, for example, "flutter symbolize -i  -d /out/android/app.android-arm64.symbols") or something else I have to manage for example with base64 when I send them and when I store them in database?

Answer (score 0):

Here https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/8934 I see examples. Stack trace is plain text.